# Запрос c вложеным limit'om и left join при помощи Hibernate

Tags: java, sql, hibernate, limit, criteria

Нужно проделать следующие извращения, интерпретировать которые я могу только в SQL:

```
select * 
from 
(select id, other, some, fields
 from table1 
 limit 10 offset 100) t1
left join table2 t2 on td.table1_id = t1.id
```

То есть нужно взять 10 записей из первой таблицы, независимо от того сколько подвяжется потом записей со второй. Если же `limit` вынести - "обрежется" вся выборка. Подскажите как можно извратить такое при помощи `Criteria` или других возможностей хибернейта? И нужно ли, возможно эффективнее будет написать ручками?

Comment: `LIMIT` без `ORDER BY` - лотерея...

Comment: @Akina, конечно, там есть и сортировка и в добавку пару условий но сейчас не это важно

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Criteria в последних версиях стоит под статусом @Deprecated и скоро мы с ней распрощаемся.

Вместо нее можно использовать конструктор JPA, в ном есть join но вот про вложеные селекты я не слышал.

```
 CriteriaQuery<Country> q = cb.createQuery(Country.class);
  Root<Country> c = q.from(Country.class);
  Join<Country> p = c.join("capital", JoinType.LEFT);
  q.multiselect(c, p.get("name"));
```

Вот тут еще [пример](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17154676/criteria-jpa-2-with-3-tables).

Лучше не заморачиваться и сделать это на HQL или SQL. *(Я так в принципе не люблю делать больший запросы на стороне приложения и храню их в виде вьюшек)*

Comment: Устаревшим помечен Criteria API именно специфичный для Hibernate. В будущих версиях предполагается использование JPA Criteria API.